# I'm having difficulties checking equality between rows in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, string, row, phpspreadsheet

```
 for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {                    

                        // SOMA do Débito e Crédito para Criar a Conciliação...
                        for ($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
                            $valueA = trim($worksheet->getCell('A' . $row)->getValue());
                            $valueB = $worksheet->getCell('B' . $row)->getValue();
                            $valueD = $worksheet->getCell('E' . $row)->getValue();
                            $valueE = $worksheet->getCell('F' . $row)->getValue();
                    
                            // Remover todos os caracteres, exceto letras e números, de $valueA
                            $valueA = strtolower($valueA);
                            $valueA = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $valueA);

                            if (in_array(trim($valueA), $uniqueValues)) {
                                // Valor em A repetido, mesclar células em A
                                $worksheet->mergeCells("A$row:A$lastRowIndex");

                                if (isset($valueMap[$valueA])) {
                                    $currentValueB = $worksheet->getCell('B' . $valueMap[$valueA])->getValue();
                                    $currentValueD = $worksheet->getCell('E' . $valueMap[$valueA])->getValue();
                                    $currentValueE = $worksheet->getCell('F' . $valueMap[$valueA])->getValue();

                            
                                    $worksheet->setCellValue('B' . $valueMap[$valueA], $currentValueB . ' ' . $valueB);
                                    $worksheet->setCellValue('E' . $valueMap[$valueA], $currentValueD . ' ' . $valueD);
                                    $worksheet->setCellValue('F' . $valueMap[$valueA], $currentValueE . ' ' . $valueE);
                                    $worksheet->removeRow($row);
                                    
                                }

                            } else {
                                $uniqueValues[] = $valueA;                                
                                $valueMap[$valueA] = $row; // Atualiza o mapa para a última linha de cada valor em A
                                
                            }
                            
                            $lastRowIndex = $row;
                        }
                    }
```

[image]
Notice that the highlighted row appears three times in my CSV. I'm using the PhpSpreadsheet library, but only 2 rows are recognized as 'equal.' I can't even echo the third one, and this happens with several rows, while others 'work normally.

I'm searching within my database for rows where column A is equal, and apparently, it works in some cases, but in others, it doesn't work. I've tried manipulating the strings in various ways, being careful with lowercase, special characters, and hidden spaces..."

Comment: Please paste the raw csv data from all the relevant rows into the question.